# Why does a single core need billions of transistors?

Tags: transistors, pcb, integrated-circuit

This is my understanding of a single core. It has a single pipeline which may have k stages, k being a relatively small number. Each stage of a pipeline seems like a simple operation like, fetch, decode, execute, etc. The ALU would also just need to have the logic implemented for some fixed number of operations. I can't fathom how a billion transistors could all be needed at the same time.

Comment: Cache takes up a lot of transistor equivalents (transmission gates and inverters.) How much cache is on the dice you are considering?

Comment: For the sake of the question, let's assume a total of 2MB.

Comment: It's at least 6T for SRAM. And that doesn't count the surrounding circuitry. Here's a [picture of the skylake processor from Intel](https://www.techspot.com/photos/article/2066-cpu-l1-l2-l3-cache/#2020-08-07-image-3): note that there are two 32 kb L1 caches on chip, one for data and one for cache. You can see them at the top-center and the right-center surrounded by white boxes. That's just 64 kB of L1 cache on a 1.8 billion transistor die. What percent do those two boxes look like, to you? (I get about 8% for both.) Note that this is ***nowhere near*** 2 Mb!

Comment: Can you put a reference of billions of transistors used in a single core processor? Maybe multi-core processor or SoC.

Comment: 2 MB Cache will have 96M Transistors at least.

Comment: @MituRaj intel i7, 7th gen has ~2B transistors and quad-core, so that's half a billion transistors for each core. My question would remain the same even with this number.

Comment: @jonk that still leaves ~80% right?

Comment: Add that comment about intel-i7 to the question to substantiate your point.

Comment: @Legolas Go look up the die layout for the AMD Ryzen Zen 3 die layout, which includes their L3 cache on-chip. (Where each processor will include L2, L1, and L0.) It's all over the web, as AMD is broadcasting their relative layout picture, everywhere. That will give you a relative idea of what cache means.

Comment: "simple operation like, fetch, decode, execute"? There's nothing simple about the pipelines in modern AMD or Intel CPUs. AVR maybe. Xeon no, "simple" doesn't fit at all.

Comment: In the days of the 6502, the thinking went 'how can I implement something useful on this process that allows me only 10-100k transistors?' Designers worked very hard to squeeze functionality out of as few registers as possible. Now, the question is 'my process allows me squintillions of transistors, how do I use those to make my processor slightly faster than that of the competition?' So they are used for cache, for 93-stage pipelines, scoreboards, managing microthreads, etc etc

Comment: As pointed out above, you wanted to have a multiply or divide you took tens of clocks to do it, to do it in one clock (or appear as one clock in a pipeline) is a massive explosion of logic.  Seen a chip where the multipliers for large integers were a significant percentage of the chip.

Comment: Your x86s are pulling in more functionality like pcie and other, which itself has sram buffers, etc.  These sizes are not surprising and make sense.  The pipeline itself is an almost insignificant in the gate count, the processor core in general is somewhat insignificant it is the stuff around it on the same die.  As many photos/drawings of chips will show you can see large portions, quarter of the chip, half the chip, that are one block of sram or other similar gate consuming items.

Answer (score 7):

Your assumption that a single core needs billions of transistors is wrong. Modern CPUs contain several billions of transistors but those are divided between cache memory and several cores.

*I can't fathom how a billion transistors could all be needed at the same time*

They're not "all used at the same time". As explained in the comments, modern CPUs have a lot of on-chip [Cache memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)). This needs to be fast memory as not to slow the rest of the CPU down. This means [SRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory) is used which needs at least 6 transistors per stored bit.

A modern CPU like AMD's [Ryzen 9 5900X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_3) has around 32 MegaByte of cache. That means 32 MByte x 8 = 256 MegaBits of storage space. As mentioned, for each bit we need 6 transistors so that means 256 MBit x 6 = 1536 Mega ~ **1.5 Billion transistors**

You may think that adding and subtracting would not require that many transistors and it doesn't but the numbers quickly add up if you consider that these adders do not work on one bit at the same time but are very "wide" so that for example two 128 bit numbers can be added in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Even the "ALU" is huge these days. Just to cover [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) you need:

> AVX uses sixteen YMM registers to perform a Single Instruction on Multiple pieces of Data (see SIMD). Each YMM register can hold and do simultaneous operations (math) on
> eight 32-bit single-precision floating point numbers OR  four 64-bit double-precision floating point numbers.

A full floating point arithmetic unit is not a small thing, and that requires a minimum of twelve of them. Plus all those 512-bit wide registers, and a lot of instruction decode logic for the very large number of AVX instructions.